# NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() turning everything to zero?

Tags: java, android, currency, number-formatting

I've been working on this for hours and can't find a solution...

When I use this code:

```
 NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
 System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(12385748375889879879894375893475984.03));
```

It gives me the output: $12,385,748,375,889,900,000,000,000,000,000,000.00

What's the problem??  I'm giving it a double value which should be able to contain a number much much larger than what I'm supplying, but it's giving me all these useless zeros...  Does anyone know why and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in the *size* of the `double` you're using, but the *precision*. A `double` can only store 15-16 digits of precision, even though it can hold numbers much bigger than 10<sup>16</sup>.

If you want exact decimal representations - and particularly if you're using it for currency values - you should use `BigDecimal`. Sample code:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("12385748375889879879894375893475984.03");
        System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(value));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$12,385,748,375,889,879,879,894,375,893,475,984.03
```

For the record the `double` literal 12385748375889879879894375893475984.03 has an *exact* value of 12,385,748,375,889,879,000,357,561,111,150,592.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot.  Thank you for the information.  I wasted so much time on this.

Answer (score 1):

A double can indeed hold a number of that size. Unfortunately, it cannot hold one of that *precision.*

Range is the highest and lowest values that can be represented with a type, precision is the number of digits that can be stored.

The bottom line is that doubles have a range of about 10<sup>+/-308</sup> but only about 15 decimal digits of precision. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) has some useful information about this as well.

As a fix, you should look into the [Java BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type since it has arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, checked at netbeas IDE and works fine

```
 NumberFormat currencyFormatter1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        BigDecimal data= new BigDecimal("12385748375889879879894375893475984.03");
        System.out.println(currencyFormatter1.format(data));
```